# How to install sphinx4?

Tags: java, cygwin, installation, environment-variables, sphinx4

For the vast majority of you this will probably be straightforward, but I need help installing the sphinx4 speech recognition software. In particular, using cygwin to do so.

1) how does one set the environmental path variable to the java sdk (I had to install NetBeans)

2) Does one need to install ant if the ant libraries are already present in NetBeans?

3) Is there a better way to import the sphinx jars into my .java project in NetBeans than through using Cygwin?

I don't know where I've been going wrong and could use any and all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For setting up of environment variables.**

1) Right-click the **My Computer** icon on your desktop and select Properties.

2) Click the **Advanced** tab.

3) Click the **Environment Variables** button.

4) Under **System** Variables, click New.

5) Enter the variable name as **JAVA_HOME**.

6) Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
   If your Java installation directory has a space in its path name, you should use the    shortened path name (`e.g. C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6`) in the environment variable instead.

Note for Windows users on 64-bit systems

```
Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'
```

7 )Click OK.

8) Click Apply Changes.

9) Close any command window which was open before you made these changes, and open a new command window. There is no way to reload environment variables from an active command prompt. If the changes do not take effect even after reopening the command window, restart Windows.

10) If you are running the Confluence EAR/WAR distribution, rather than the regular Confluence distribution, you may need to restart your application server.

**Does one need to install ant if the ant libraries are already present in NetBeans?**

No. You don't need to install it again.

**Is there a better way to import the sphinx jars into my .java project in NetBeans than through using Cygwin?**

Using **Cygwin(linux environment in Windows)** definately works , but unsure about any other method.